# cocos2dx: RunningScene != Scene You just Replace

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, cocos2d-x

I have this code for cocos2d-x 3.x:

```
void MainMenu::StartGame(cocos2d::Ref* pSender)
{
    auto director = Director::getInstance();
    auto newScene = Scene::create();
    director->replaceScene(newScene); //run
    Scene *maybeNewScene = director->getRunningScene();
    CCASSERT ( maybeNewScene == newScene , "...") ;          //Assert Fail

    auto hudLayer= HUD::create();
    hudLayer->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
    scene->addChild(hudLayer, Z_NORMAL);
}
```

But When I get runnign scene by `director->getRunningScene()`, It gives me the scene which was running before calling `director->replaceScene()`. (the scene which is going to be destructed soon)

When I checked `replaceScene()` function, This function places `newScene` in some varibale called `_nextScene` but not assigned it to `_runningScene` .

**Question:**  How can I access `newScene`, just some lines further? ( for example in `HUD::init()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from @mannewalis

> The reason your scene is not the running scene is because it it only
>   gets set the **next frame**, or **even later** if there is a transition
>   running.
>
> You could add you HUD create code in the new scene **onEnter** method, I
>   believe runningScene will be set by then, but possibly not if there is
>   a transition running, in which case you should add your HUD create
>   code to the **onEnterTransitionDidFinish** method. You can even use a
>   lambda method to do it by calling
>   **setonEnterTransitionDidFinishCallback**.