# Why current scene in cocos2dx has no children when accessed from outside scene class?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I want to access a sprite in a scene, but I cannot get the running scene from outside the scene class.

The scene is created using:

```
Scene* MyScene::createScene() {
    auto scene = Scene::create();
    auto layer = MyScene::create();
    scene->addChild(layer);
    return scene;
}

bool MyScene::init() {
    this->addChild(sprite,100, 1234);
}
```

But if I then access the running scene from outside the class, it has no children.

```
Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()
//should be the MyScene instance with sprite children, but has no children.
```

I also tried giving the scene layer a tagname, but with the same result.

```
scene->addChild(layer,100,TAGNAME);
...
Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->getChildByTag(TAGNAME)
//returns NULL because getRunningScene has no children.
```

The only way I can access the scene is making a static reference in my AppDelegate, but this doesn't seem a proper way. **How can I get the current scene correctly from outside the class?**

Comment: I think this question is duplicate of [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/87217/cocos2dx-your-runningscene-scene-you-just-replace).

Answer (score 2):

Your `layer` is a child of `scene`.

Try a `Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->getChildrenCount()` and you will find only 1 child: `layer`

You will have to search the children of `layer` to find the one you need :)

I would use:

```
auto scene = Scene::create();
auto layer = HelloWorld::create();
scene->addChild(layer,0,999); // add layer as a child to scene
```

In the `init()`:

```
this->addChild(yourNode,100,TAGNAME); //this points to layer!
```

To find yourNode with tag

```
auto scene = cocos2d::Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene();
auto layer = scene->getChildByTag( 999 );
auto node = layer->getChildByTag( TAGNAME );
```

I think this will answer your question.